# htaccess to hide subdirectory without changing base root, and with exception of another subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website `https://example.com`

which has 2 subdirectories, `https://example.com/admin` and `https://example.com/store`.

1. I want to hide `/store` from URL so my requests would look like:
   `https://example.com/shop.php?id=someid`
2. But Also, I want `https://example.com/admin/index.php` to work.
3. I found some answers that achieve both 1 and 2 but they change base root so all my css,js, images don't load

So far I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^store/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
RewriteRule !^store/ store%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This achieves 1 but not 2.

Comment: Do you want your `/admin/foobar` URLs to look like `/foobar` ?

Comment: no. /admin subdirectory can remain as is, although if even if it does look like /foobar, it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Then what exactly is not working for you with the rule?

Comment: sorry, I was not clear enough, example.com/admin is throwing 404.
I presume because the request becomes example.com/store/admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
> RewriteRule ^store/(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
> RewriteRule !^store/ store%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
> ```

In the second rule... exclude the `/admin` subdirectory (as well as `/store`) in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. And add a *condition* to  exclude requests that contain a file extension (ie. `.css`, `.js`, `.png`, etc.). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteRule !^(store|admin)($|/) store%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Alternatively (although marginally less efficient), exclude any request that already maps to a physical file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^(store|admin)($|/) store%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

This rule assumes you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/store` subdirectory that also uses the rewrite engine. (But if that is the case then the first rule isn't actually doing anything.)

Unless you are hosting multiple domains/sites then you don't need the first condition that checks the requested `Host`.

Comment: Your first solution although worked, but example.com/shop.php was giving 404
Your second solution worked absolutely flawlessly.
Thanks for brief explanation too, I'll definitely try and understand readwrite rules better. 
Thanks for the perfect answer.